# Does $X \lor Y = (X \sqcup Y)/\{x_0, y_0\}$ depends on the points $x_0, y_0$?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X, Y$ two topological spaces and $x_0,y_0$ in $X, Y$ respectively. We denote the wedge product of $(X, x_0)$ and $(Y, y_0)$ by $X \lor Y$, such that
$$X \lor Y = (X \sqcup Y)/\{x_0, y_0\}.$$
This might by a silly question, but why there is no mention of $x_0, y_0$ in the notation of the wedge product $X \lor Y$? Is it because it does not depend on $x_0, y_0$ or just because mathematicians are lazy?

Comment: It's because mathematicians are lazy

Comment: Generally, it very much depends on the choice of $x_0, y_0$. Think for example of $X = Y = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$ and create two non-homeomorphic spaces via the wedge

Comment: Possible answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399087/when-wedge-sum-of-topological-spaces-are-independent-of-choosing-base-points-up

Comment: One shouldn't confuse being lazy with not giving superfluous information. Generically, there is no danger in confusion in not specifying the base point.

Comment: It's a construction in the category of "pointed spaces". So the points are always understood.